# How to get result from an API request in wordpress? WCF

Tags: php, wordpress, api, wcf

My client share me an api url like "http://xxx.xx.xx.xx/RemT/Service1.svc" , UserID = "rem" , password ="abc123" and if i send request with this parameters "rin=12345" it should give me some result. I don't know which API type it is, maybe some WCF? Can anyone assist me how to test this in POSTMAN and how to call results in Wordpress custom code? Thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

From the service Url, it indeed belongs to WCF service, a kind of SOAP web service. However, it also can be Rest API, which can be simply called by an HTTP request.
In general, the service will publish the service `WSDL` page, then we use the below SOAP client class to call the service.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php
In the `DotNet` platform, we generate a client proxy to call the service as like calling a local method.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client
If the service is a kind of RestAPI created by WCF, we can simply test it in `Postman`. We had better ask the client for more details.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.